# How to un-share a shared folder?

Tags: windows, network-shares, shared-folders

I have shared a folder which I want to now un-share.

Folder properties:

[image]

Advanced sharing:

[image]

I don't see an option to stop the folder from being shared. What is the way to un-share a shared folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots, looks like the folder is *already* not shared directly.

It's only accessible as part of a broader `\\▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓\Users` share – and when the parent folder is shared there's no way to individually unshare subfolders.

You can use `fsmgmt.msc` to see a list of all shares configured on the system (and delete them).

Comment: I originally shared the following folder: `C:\Users\myname\foldername`. But as you say when I right click on the `Users` folder that shows me that it is `Users` folder that is actually shared. Why is that shared automatically when I actually shared a child folder?

Comment: My guess is that either a) it was already shared _before,_ or b) you used the Windows "share wizard" which probably does it that way with the goal of creating consistent paths.